# Active Noise cancellation for non periodic signals

Tags: discrete-signals, noise, adaptive-filters, system-identification, lms

I observed that the coded algorithm for active noise cancellation is not able to cancel some of the signals like a human voice. Is there any solution for this? Can we really cancel non-periodic signals at least at the software level correctly? What changes do I need to make in the code?

Comment: One solution : Sound Masking

https://www.softdb.com/sound-masking/technology/#what-is-sound-masking